# How to put a div fix at bottom of the page && above footer using css

Tags: css

I have a box (shopping cart) which I want it to be fixed at the bottom of the page.
But if the page is not long enough, or the user scroll to the end of the page, so that the footer is in the viewport. In this case I want the shopping cart box to be right above the footer.

Is it possible to do this without JS?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. Also at least once read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Seems you want the opposite of `position:sticky`. A quick and dirty test shows that `position:sticky: bottom:3em` doesn't work as intended. Shame.

Answer (score 3):

**answer only for the fun**, you should relay on javascript to make it solid.

There could be a risky trick with `position:sticky`, floatting pseudo and `display` resetting.

```css
aside,
footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: white;
  border: solid;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 1;
}
footer {
  z-index: 0;/*hide it from aside */
}
html:before {/* push sticky elements down */
  content: "";
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
margin:0;
  display: inline;/* get body scrolling and block formatting context off the game */
}
```

```html
<main>main<br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> <br/> end main</main>
<aside>aside at bottom !</aside>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

You can play a little with and test [it](https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/OxgYwY) with content, but remenber, its not reliable, sticky not implemented everywhere and behavior can varie from a browser to another, from an update to another in the most funny and unexpected ways.

Comment: Neat. I was attempting this as well, but I failed miserably.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is not very clear, so I'll try to answer it as best as I understand.

1. **Getting your footer to sit on the bottom of a short page**

   To achieve this effect, **flexbox** comes in very handy. First, set the 
   `body`'s style to :

   ```
   display:flex; 
   flex-direction: column;
   min-height: 100vh;
   ```

   Setting `display:flex` makes all child elements on the page (i.e. in the `body` tag)     **flex items**, hence offering us the opportunity to style said elements as such. Setting `flex-direction` to column also ensures that all child elements of `body` are stacked *vertically*.

   Now, the `min-height: 100vh;` makes the body span at least 100% of the viewport height.

   To get an element (in this case your shopping cart box. Let's call it `.shopping-cart-box` from here on out) to "push" the footer to the bottom of the viewport, you can then set it's flex (or flex-grow, to be precise) value to 1. This makes it take up the rest of the available space.

   Remember the body is at **100%** of viewport height. If your navigation menu takes up, say, **10%** and footer takes up **5%** of the viewport height respectively, the .shopping-cart-box with    `flex: 1;` will then fill up the rest of the **85%** of viewport height, essentially "pushing" the footer to the bottom of the page.
2. **Making your shopping cart box sit on top of the footer**

   Now that we have the footer at the bottom and .shopping-cart-box taking up the rest of the available space, we need to force its contents to align bottom.

   We can do this by adding

   ```
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: column;
   ```

   to .shopping-cart-box. That, again, allows us to treat all child elements of `.shopping-cart-box` as flex items.

Assuming we have a child element `.shopping-cart-product` inside .shopping-cart-box, we can set align it to the bottom of its parent container in two ways: 
using

```
margin-top: auto
```

or

```
align-self: flex-end
```

A visual representation can be found below with the provided code snippet:

```css
/* RELEVANT CODE*/
.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.shopping-cart-box {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.shopping-cart-product {
  margin-top: auto; /* or align-self: flex-end; */
}












/*CODE FOR AESTHETICS */

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 12px;
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
}



/* Footer */ 
.footer {
  background-color: #013940;
  padding: 18px 12px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.ui.item.menu,
.ui.item.menu .item {
  width: 40% !important;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body class="body">
  <header>
    <nav class="nav">
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <h1>
          ShopperStack</h1>
      </a>

      <ul class="ui two item menu nav--links">
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="item">
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <div class="container">
    <p>
      This is a block of text on the upper part of the page
    </p>
  </div>


  <div class="shopping-cart-box">
    <div class="shopping-cart-product container">
      <form action="" class="ui segment form">
        <div class="field">
          <h3 class="header">Place Order</h3>
          <p class="label">ACME SuperBlaster 4000</p>
          <input type="submit" value="Buy Now" class="ui button">
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <footer class="footer">
    <section class="container">
      <h3>Thanks for visiting ShopperStack!</h3>
    </section>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: The question is still pretty clear and this is not the desired result.

Comment: When the footer is not seen on the scroll-able page, the cart needs to be positioned at the bottom right preferably but when the user scrolls to the end of the page and sees the footer, the cart needs to be placed right above it and that position is not the same as before esp. if the footer takes a lot of height.

Comment: Ahh, that makes more sense. Thanks for the insight.